# bootstrap navigation with hamburger on left and dropdown on right

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Stackoverflow as well as Bootstrap. I hope I have asked this in the right way.

What I want to achieve is a mobile app like navigation with hamburger on the left with push menu and drop down menu on the right similar to an android app with three dots which reveal additional menu options like settings on fixed navigation bar on top.

I was able to achieve the hamburger correctly by using jasny bootstrap offcanvas. That too has some problem that it does not display the top bar on large screens. I got the right setting menu, but it does not collapse, and the top bar is not static. Here is the code I have till now.
    
    
    
        App Style Menu

```
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas">
        <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">App Style Menu</a>
        <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Flow Properties<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App Nav</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me get this right

Comment: You are showing two different nav bars in your question.  Which one are you looking to add the image to?

Comment: Actually I want a single navbar which on large and medium screen sits on the top of the screen with main menu left aligned and setting aligned to right, and on small screens the main menu goes into a hamburger on left and settings stays on the right side. But don't know how to achieve this. I will add fiddles soon to clarify the question more